# Evaluate $\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{zRe(z)}{\overline{z}}$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

> $$\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{z\cdot Re(z)}{\overline{z}}$$

$$\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{z\cdot Re(z)}{\overline{z}}=\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{(x+yi)\cdot x}{x-yi}=\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{x^2+yxi}{x-yi}\cdot\frac{x+yi}{x+yi}=\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{x^3+yx^2i+y^2xi-y^2x}{x^2+y^2}=\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{x^3-y^2x}{x^2+y^2}+i\frac{yx^2+y^2x}{x^2+y^2}$$

How should I continue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $|\operatorname{re} z | \le |z| $. Hence for
$z \neq 0$ we have
$|{z \operatorname{re} z \over \overline{z}}| \le  {|z|^2 \over |z|} = |z|$.

Hence it follows that the limit is zero.

Comment: Isnt it $\frac{|z|^2}{|\overline{z}|}$?

Comment: @gbox: $|\overline{z}| = |z|$.

Comment: The general point is that it is a little easier to work with the $z$s as much as possible rather than going to $x,y$ coordinates.

Comment: from limit calculation point of view, we prove that the absolute value of the expression is zero, and therefore so the expression limit is zero?

Comment: Yes, by definition we have $L=\lim_{z \to c} f(z)$ **iff** $\lim_{z\to c} |f(z)-L| = 0$. In the above case $L=0$.

Comment: Sorry, I have already forgot, we find the limit on a greater or equal expression of the absolute value, and due to the sequence theorem what you have wrote take place?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are asking, but if we know that $\lim_{z \to 0} g(z) = 0$ and $|f(z)| \le |g(z)|$ then we know that $\lim_{z \to 0} f(z) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Using your notation:

$$\frac{x(x+iy)}{x-iy}=\frac{x^3-xy^2}{x^2+y^2}+\frac{2x^2y}{x^2+y^2}i$$

and using polar coordinates (why can we? Detail the following):

$$\begin{cases}\cfrac{x^3-xy^2}{x^2+y^2}=r\left(\cos^3\theta-\cos\theta\sin^2\theta\right)\xrightarrow[r\to0]{}0\\{}\\
\cfrac{2x^2y}{x^2+y^2}=r\left(\cos^2\theta\sin\theta\right)\xrightarrow[r\to0]{}0\end{cases}\;\;\implies\frac{ z\,\text{Re}\,z}{\overline z}\xrightarrow[z\to0]{}0$$

Comment: $x^2+y^2=r$ so is should be $r^{-1}$ no? (not that it has effect on the answer, just for learning purpose)

Comment: @gbox I can't see why: $\;x^2+y^2\;$ is *in the denominator* of the expressions...And it would have a terrible effect on the result: the limits wouldn't exist finitely.

Comment: I have multiply the expression by $\frac{x+yi}{x+yi}$, so how did you get the $r$ form? $x=cos\theta,y=sin\theta$

Comment: @gbox For example, $$\frac{x^3-xy^2}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{r^3\cos^3\theta-r\cos \theta\,r^2\sin^2\theta}{r^2\cos^2\theta+r^2\sin^2\theta}=\frac{r^3\left(\cos^3\theta-\cos\theta\sin^2\theta\right)}{r^2(\cos^2\theta\sin^2\theta}=r\,()...etc.$$

Answer (score 0):

Bounding the numerators of real and imaginary parts:
$$|x^3-y^2x|\le|x|(x^2 + y^2),$$
$$|yx^2+y^2x|\le\max\{|x|,|y|\}(x^2 + y^2).$$
So the limit is zero.